# tls1.2 signature algorithm extensions

Tags: tls1.2

Using Openssl 1.0.1t using C, I see in the tls1.h file there are definitions for a signature algorithm extension (`TLSEXXT_TYPE_signature_algorithm`) and for specifying signatures/hashes to be supported (`TLSEXT_signature_rsa TLSEXT_hash_sha256`).

My question is what call do I need to make in order to implement these things and force a signature algorithm extension showing I support `rsa/sha256` in the client hello message?